# How to define global variable in groovy for jenkins job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, global-variables

I'm using `Extended Choice Parameter` plugin to ask user for some parameters.
It has inputs:

- Countries
- Environments

So, I defined first parameter `countries` and selected multiple choice and `Groovy Script` for value.
I posted some script, which gets `json`, parses it, and it has this in the end:

```
json.objectEntries.attributes.each { j-> 
 j.objectAttributeValues[4].displayValue.each{ host ->
 hosts.add(host+","+j.objectAttributeValues[6].displayValue.join("")+","+j.objectAttributeValues[14].displayValue.join(";") ) 
 }
 j.objectAttributeValues[14].displayValue.each{ country ->  countries.add(country) }
 j.objectAttributeValues[6].displayValue.each{ environment ->  environments.add(environment)  }
} 

Environments = environments.unique(true).join(",")
Hosts = hosts.join(";")

countries.unique(true).each {c -> println c}
```

Then I added second parameter - `Environments`.
Almost same as first one, but script now look like that:

```
Environments.each{ e -> println e}
```

and from that point everything is fine and I can freely use variables `Environments` and `Countries` in later steps.
But I can't pass variable `Hosts`.

And question is - How to to define variable on first script, so it will pass variable across whole job?

Comment: Are you using a [declarative pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline) or a [scripted pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#scripted-pipeline)? You can easily create a global variable in a declarative pipeline by declaring the variable at the top of the pipeline file, above the `pipeline` block.

Comment: it is a freestyle job